# Fixed points of a composition of adjunctions

Tags: category-theory, soft-question

Let
$$\mathcal C\rightleftarrows \mathcal D\rightleftarrows \mathcal E$$
be two adjunctions $F\dashv U$ and $F'\dashv U'$. Composing them yields an adjunction
$$(F'\circ F\dashv U\circ U')\colon \mathcal C\rightleftarrows \mathcal E.$$

**Question:** Given one knows the fixed points of $F\dashv U$ and $F'\dashv U'$, is there any information one can derive about the fixed points of the composition adjunction $F'\circ F\dashv U\circ U'$? And vice versa?

*Recall:* The fixed points of an adjunction $F\dashv U\colon\mathcal C\rightleftarrows \mathcal D$ on the side $\mathcal C$ are all objects $X\in\mathcal C$ such that the unit component $X\to UFX$ is an isomorphism. The fixed points on the side $\mathcal D$ are all objects such that the counit component is an isomorphism.

Comment: Let $\eta, \eta'$ be the units of the adjunction $F \dashv U$ and $F' \dashv U'$ respectively. A fixed point $X$ of $F \dashv U$ is a fixed point of $F'F \dashv UU'$ if and only if $U \eta'_{FX}$ is an isomorphism. This follows quickly from the definition of the unit of $F'F \dashv UU'$. I don't think one can say anything further than that, given the situation is very general here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer really depends on the adjunctions you consider. Here's an example where you can't say anything interesting.

A category $\cal C$ has a terminal object iff the terminal functor $u : {\cal C} \to 1$ has a right adjoint $t : 1 \to{\cal C}$.

The [category of] fixpoints of such an adjunction

$$ u : {\cal C} \leftrightarrows 1 : t $$

consist of the discrete subcategory of $\cal C$ over the terminal object $\{t\}$.

So, for *any* two categories $\cal C,D$ having a terminal object, and *any* adjunction $F :{\cal C} \rightleftarrows {\cal D}: G$ we are in the situation that the fixpoints of the composite adjunction

$${\cal C} \rightleftarrows {\cal D} \rightleftarrows 1$$

consist of the subcategory spanned by the terminal object of $\cal C$, no matter what the fixpoints of $(F,G)$ were.